# How to implement I18N and L10N in a serverless architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm researching building a project on AWS as a serverless architecture but I'm curious how I should go about implementing internationalization and localization.  Should I pre-process the output with Lambda to generate translations?  Is there a recommended UI library to use and just do it completely on the front end?

If the best option is to do it all on the front end I'd prefer a library that can stand on its own in a Vanilla JS system.

Comment: Did you find a solution that you're willing to share? What text is coming from your backed that needs i18n and L10n?

Comment: I never did and unfortunately the project was shuddered.